# Howto disable mirror repository in maven settings

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

In my maven ~./.m2/settings.xml I have defined a mirror and some repositories:

```
 <mirrors>
    <mirror>
    <id>someid</id>
        .....
    </mirro>
 </mirrors>
...

<profiles>
    <profile>
         <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                     <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                 </activation>
                 <repositories>
            <repository>                                                                    <id>repo....</id>
....

         </profile>
</profiles>
```

This works fine.

There are some projects where I want do disable the mirror and the default profile.
I know that i can define a seperate profile for the repositories, but i don't know how I can tell the maven eclipse plugin not to use the default profile or a specific profile.
Also: how can I change the mirror for a project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the `settings.xml` file, remove the `mirror` entry and tell maven to use with the `--settings` *file* command line option.

Use XSLT or a command line tool like [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to automate the process:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N 's=http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0' --delete "//s:mirror" settings.xml
```

prints a new `settings.xml` file to `stdout` which doesn't contain any mirror settings.

**Update**: The XML namespace has recently changed. Make sure you use the same string as the one at the top of the file. Kudos to [Roman Ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015848/roman-ivanov) for pointing this out.

Comment: If an XSLT-based tool is unavailable, in sed:

`sed settings.xml -e "/<mirrors>/,/<\/mirrors>/ d"`

Comment: be careful with namespace, it should be same as in file most recent settings schema is different `1.1.0`, so use 
`xmlstarlet ed --inplace -N s="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" -d "//s:mirrors" settings.xml`

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately this is impossible with single settings.xml. There is feature request in Maven JIRA, vote for this!

- [JIRA ticket MNG-3525](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3525)
- [Pull Request to implement the feature](https://github.com/apache/maven/pull/71)

Workaround is to have two settings.xml and running maven with selected configuration:

```
mvn -s my-settings.xml
```

Comment: Wow, the cited feature request is now open for 7 years.

Comment: Nice idea.. This answer saves lots of my time ! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple `settings.xml` is not necessary I think to do this.

**It is possible to control mirrors using profiles.**

I can use a property for my repository `id` for example a suffix `${repo-suffix}`

```
$ mvn help:effective-pom | grep "<distributionManagement>" -A 3
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>deployment${repo-suffix}</id>
      <name>Internal Releases</name>
```

Then I can add `repo-suffix` to a profile for example to give it value `-1`.

```
<profile>
  <id>my-profile</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
    <properties>
      <repo-suffix>-1</repo-suffix>
      ...
```

This way I now have a dynamically defined repository id in pom files.

```
$ mvn help:effective-pom | grep "<distributionManagement>" -A 3
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>deployment-1</id>
      <name>Internal Releases</name>
```

For these this `deployment-1` repository I can define mirrors in my `settings.xml`. This is effectively the same as being able to put a mirror in a profile.

Answer (score 1):

The entries in `settings.xml` applies to all the maven projects on the system and thus is not meant to be tailored for individual projects.

If you want different projects to have different `profiles`, then you should specify them in the project's `pom`.  You need not have `<profiles>` section in your `~/m2/settings.xml`.

As for `<mirrors>` they apply to `repositories` that you want to mirror.  You can choose which repositories need to be mirrored, but not which projects should use the mirror and which should not.  You can always run the project in `offline` mode, if you do not want it to download from a remote repository.